# How to correctly handle blur and focus in React Native Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen in a React Native app which is made by 2 tabs. Everytime I switch tab I want to initiate a polling operation with my server to get the content of the tab. I'm achieving this by doing:

```
const [pollingId, setPollingId] = useState<number>(0);

useEffect(() => {
  clearInterval(pollingId);
  setPollingId(window.setInterval(() => loadList(activeTab), 60000));
}, [activeTab]);
```

and this works fine.

The problem begins when I navigate on another screen: What I want to do is:

- stop the polling (whatever it is)
- navigate to the second screen
- when I return on the 2 tabs screen the polling must restart

But when i do `navigation.navigate("Screen2")`, the first screen is not unmounted, so I can't put the `clearInterval(pollingId)` in the `useEffect`'s return function.

I was trying to use the blur and focus events of React Navigation by doing:

```
const subscribe = () => {
  navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
  console.debug('focus');
    setPollingId(window.setInterval(() => loadList(activeTab), 60000));
  });
};

const unsubscribe = () => {
  navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    console.debug('blur');
    clearInterval(pollingId);
  });
};
```

But this is causing the events to stack on each other if I countinue to go forward and backward. What is the best practice to do what I'm not managing to do?

Comment: Which react-navigation version are you using?

Comment: This is my package.json: `"@react-navigation/core": "^5.12.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.8.0",`

Comment: Did you try the hook `useFocusEffect` from `@react-navigation/native`?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for adding navigation event listeners would be to set a constant to catch the return value of `addListener()`, then return that value, all inside of a `useEffect` call. That `unsubscribe` function gets called automatically whenever the navigation framework needs to clean up the effect. That should prevent you from getting multiple calls to the same event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    console.debug('focus');
    setPollingId(window.setInterval(() => loadList(activeTab), 60000));
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Then, do something similar for the blur event:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    console.debug('blur');
    clearInterval(pollingId);
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```